# Cannot push from git

Tags: github

When I am using git push, it shows

remote: You must verify your email address.
remote: See https://github.com/settings/emails.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mynickname/reponame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

But I already verified my email address.

On the other hand, I can pull and add, only push is not available. I can also push by using Github Desktop.

Could someone help me? Many thanks

Comment: Does running `git config --get user.email` on the computer you are pushing from give the same email you verified?

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: This question sounds related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551143/change-username-github-you-must-verify-your-email-address-403-error-on-git-pus and has an answer that might be of help for you.

Comment: I just tried this method, but still not working. I didn't change my username before. And I am using Mac OS, it's not feasible to delete user information like that...

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem as you and I can not solve it.
But there is a second way to push you commits.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:bitfish-xyz/viewport.git
$ git pull -u origin master
```

Use SSH instead of HTTPS.

This work fine for me. If I can solve this directly, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your git configuration is using a different email address from what you verified. Check that `git config user.email` outputs the same email that you used on GitHub. If it does not, set it with `git config user.email "correct@email.com"`, then try pushing again.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the email address, and they are the same and verified.

Answer (score 0):

There is an osxkeychain in Mac, we can delete account information by using

1. git config --local --unset credential.helper
2. git config --global --unset credential.helper
3. sudo git config --system --unset credential.helper

Just asked GitHub Support, the official solution: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/